# Transition CSS3 does not work

Tags: html, css, transition

I was trying the examples from w3schools: http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_transition1 but I doing the same in my CSS and it does not work.

CSS:

```
 nav > ul > li{
     display: inline-block; 
     padding: 0px; 
     margin: 0px;  
     transition: width 2s;
 }

 nav > ul > li:hover{
     width: 20%; 
 }
```

hover works without problems, but does not the transition... this should be easy

Comment: Did you try adding width to  nav > ul > li {}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The browser typically cannot transition an element's property without having both a start and end value. Give it an initial width.

```
nav > ul > li {
    width: 100px;
```

You'll notice that if you remove the initial width from **[the example you gave](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_transition1)** the transition ceases to function.

Comment: I think you mean css not javascript.

Answer (score 3):

You need to define the initial/start `width` of the element before you apply `transition`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5a5oe33k/)

```
nav > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    transition: width 2s;
    background: #f00;
    width: 0; /* Add this */
}

nav > ul > li:hover {
    width: 20%;
}
```

**Some tips** :

- Don't use `px` if the value is `0` so unit doesn't matter.
- I hope you know that you are using `inline-block` so white-space will occur
- Don't use too specific selectors if not required, assign a `class` to the parent element to uniquely identify the element. So instead of writing <s>`nav > ul > li`</s> you can write `.some-class-nav > li`. Also you can get rid of `>` if you are sure that your `li` items won't have child `li`